# Radnumerictextbox accepting characters and alphabets/

Tags: asp.net, webforms, textbox, telerik

I am using a simple RadNumericTextBox.
But none of the properties are working.
Below is the code snippet:

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID = "Test" runat = "server" width = "125px"/>
```

My requirements:

1. Group Separator
2. SelectionOnFocus = "SelectAll"

I have tried everything for above two but none of the things worked.

Observations:

1. maxlength property is working if i use.
2. minvalue property is also working.
3. Decimal value is also working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using the properties of telerik controls such as Radnumeric texboxes, page initialize event must be declared, i.e., Page_Init().

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the needed properties in this way:

```
 <telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="Test" Runat="server" width = "125px" Type="Number" SelectionOnFocus="SelectAll">
      <NumberFormat GroupSeparator="." />
    </telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

Let us know if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.
Type="Number" should be added.

Comment: Hi, I have noticed one thing that the above solution works only if the codebehind has a Page_Init() event. If this event is removed, then it doesn't works at all. I didn't understand why ?